# How to localize Neutronium-based UI using .RESX files?

Tags: c#, wpf, neutronium

I use [Neutronium](https://github.com/NeutroniumCore/Neutronium) library for a HTML-based C# UI.

I want to be able to use strings from a .RESX resource conveniently, not wrapping every string in a resource-accessing property of the ViewModel.

How achieve this more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another alternative possible with Neutronium v.1.0.0 which has just been released. 
The solution use vue-i18n has infrastructure and T4 template to convert .resx files into JSON file that then will be imported in javascript by webpack.

Configuration (install.js file):

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from './Dictionary'

function install(vue) {
    //Call vue use here if needed
    vue.use(VueI18n);
}

function vueInstanceOption() {
    const i18n = new VueI18n({
        locale: 'fr-FR', // set locale
        messages, // set locale messages
    });

    //Return vue global option here, such as vue-router, vue-i18n, mix-ins, .... 
    return {i18n}
}

export {
    install,
    vueInstanceOption
}
```

t4 template:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Globalization" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Resources" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".json" #>
<# 
    Langages = new [] { "en-US", "fr-FR", "pt-BR" };
    Resources = new []{"Resource"};
#>
{
 <# var first = true;
 PushIndent("    ");
 foreach (var langage in Langages) {
    if (!first){
        WriteLine("},");
    }
    first =false;
    WriteLine($@"""{langage}"":{{");
    PushIndent("    ");
    foreach(var resource in Resources){
        WriteLine($@"""{resource}"":{{");
        PushIndent("    ");
        var dic = GetDictionary(resource, langage);
        DisplayDictionary(dic);
        PopIndent();
        WriteLine("}");
    }
    PopIndent();
 } 
 WriteLine("}");
 PopIndent();
 #>
}
<#+
private string[] Langages;

private string[] Resources;

private void DisplayDictionary(IDictionary<string,string> dictionary){
    var first = true;
    foreach(var entry in dictionary){
        if (!first){
            WriteLine(",");
        }
        first = false;
        Write($@"""{entry.Key}"":""{entry.Value}""");
    }
    WriteLine("");
}

private IDictionary<string,string> GetDictionary(string resourceName, string langage){
    var path = this.Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(TargetPath)");
    var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Example.Option.CFx.Vue." + resourceName, asm);
    var rs = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo(langage), true, true);
    return rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(dicEntry => (string)dicEntry.Key, dicEntry => (string)dicEntry.Value);            
}
#>
```

Then you can use localization normally in all files.

Ex: App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ $t("Resource.Welcome") }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ $t("Resource.MyFriend") }}</h2>     
  </div>
</template>
```

Complete code [here](https://github.com/NeutroniumCore/Neutronium/tree/master/Examples/Example.Option.CFx.Vue)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ResourceManager.GetResourceSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset.aspx) to convert resource in a dictionary and then use this dictionary in the ViewModel

Here is a complete solution compatible with upcoming version 1.0.0

**ViewModel:**

> ```
> public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
> {
>    private Dictionary<string, string> _Localization;
>    public Dictionary<string, string> Localization
>    {
>        get { return _Localization; }
>        private set { Set(ref _Localization, value, nameof(Localization)); }
>    }
>
>    private string _Langage;
>    public string Langage
>    {
>         get { return _Langage; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (Set(ref _Langage, value, nameof(Langage)))
>             {
>                  UpdateLangage();
>             }           
>         }
>    }
>
>    private void UpdateLangage()
>    {
>        var rs = Resource.ResourceManager
>                         .GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo(_Langage), true, true);
>        Localization = rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
>                         .ToDictionary(dicEntry => (string)dicEntry.Key, dicEntry => (string)dicEntry.Value);            
>    }
>
>    public string[] Langages => new[] {"en-US", "pt-BR", "fr-FR"};
>
>    public MainViewModel()
>    {
>      Langage = "en-US";
>    }
> }
> ```

**Vue file:**

```
 <template>
        <div id="app" class="fluid container">
            <div id="main-menu" class="jumbotron logo">
                <img src="./assets/logo.png">
                <p>{{Localization.NeutroniumLocalizationExample}}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span>{{Localization.Language}}</span>
                <select v-model="Langage">
                    <option v-for="lang in Langages" :value="lang">{{lang}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h1>{{Localization.Hello}}</h1>
                <h2>{{Localization.Welcome}}</h2>
                <h3>{{Localization.MyFriend}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Complete solution [here](https://github.com/NeutroniumCore/Neutronium/tree/master/Examples/Example.Localization.Cfx.Vue)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that framework but one option could be to use dynamic types. Warning - none of this is tested...

Create a "dynamic" class that will be responsible for exposing the string resources:

```
public class ResourceProvider : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        var resourceName = binder.Name;

        result = MyResources.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);
        // You'll want some error checking here, and return false if the resource does not exist 
        // (or throw an exception, return a default string, etc).
        return true;
    }
}
```

(`MyResources` is the name of the resx file. Remember to change the resource file's access modifier combobox from Internal to Public if it lives in a separate project).

Next, in your VM (or VM base class if you need this functionality in other views), create an instance of the above class and expose it as a 'dynamic' property type, e.g.

```
public dynamic ViewResources { get; private set; }

...

ViewResources = new ResourceProvider();
```

In your HTML, while I don't know the exact syntax for that framework, you should now be able to bind using expressions like:

```
"ViewResources.Hello"
```

(where "Hello" is the name of a string resource in the resx file).

This will also work in your VM C# code, i.e.

```
var s = ViewResources.Hello;
```

Comment: A clever usage of `DynamicObject`, but Neutronium doesn't seem to internally support reflecting over such objects. So it didnt't work even with pre-declaring the properties with `GetDynamicMemberNames()`.https://github.com/NeutroniumCore/Neutronium/blob/78024124d1da55f8d5d33344ca482e7f9a8c2419/Neutronium.Core/Infra/Reflection/PropertyAccessor.cs

Comment: I'm currently thinking of passing the resources as list of stringKey-stringValue pairs to Neutronium (it certainly supports this), and then populating the JS-side ViewModel with properties. I'll publish my own solution if it works.

Comment: Neutronium is currently not designed to work with dynamic objects. That said, it could be improved to accept dynamic objects implementing GetMemberNames which not the case of the proposed solution.

Comment: version 1.0 of Neutronium will support dynamic Object conversion providade that they implement GetMemberNames.